# How do I estimate the parameters of an MA(q) process?

Tags: time-series, estimation

It is relatively easy to estimate the parameters of an autoregressive $AR(p)$ process. How do I do with a moving average $MA(q)$ process?

Comment: Why the vote to close as off-topic? Time series analysis is very important in stat-arb/HFT trading.

Comment: In my opinion, it is too elementary to be on topic. Every textbook on time series analysis covers this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Estimating $MA(q)$ models is significantly harder than $AR(p)$ models. Eviews, MATLAB and R can use multiple algorithms which are all based on some form of maximum likelihood estimation.  You can look at the source of MATLAB and R or the excellent Eviews documentation.

However, I strongly advise *against* rolling your own since efficient and well tested algorithms are widely available.

For the interested, this [paper](https://web.archive.org/web/20100616120721/http://statistics.berkeley.edu/classes/s244/as154.pdf) describes the method (with code) used by the [R arima package](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/arima.html). You can see from the abstract the method it is quite complicated.

Comment: Thanks. I know mature libraries are the way to go in production applications, but I am simply interested in this problem.